# What is an un-ambiguous tag for map as in Google Maps

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, tags

Also, would it be worth creating such a tag on Stack Overflow for various map based services, APIs, geo location, etc.

Comment: Such a tag would be too general - it would not stand on its own (i.e. would require other tags to give it context).

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the `google-maps` tag? Unless you're looking for something more specific.

Comment: Actually looking for less specific than the google-maps tag. I think what I have in mind doesn't make sense as it would be too general as Oded pointed out.

Comment: SO likes to divide things down to make them clearer. There's likely a tag for what you're looking for buried somewhere.